# Getting information submitted in form created by HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I looked at similar questions concerning this topic but still unable to fully understand how to obtain data entered in a form created by HTML.

Here is what I wanted to do:

- Create a form (via HTML)
- On form submission, data entered is used them to replace the appropriate placeholder keys
  in an existing Google Document Template.
- email the new Document with replaced text to the user.

I follow this [tutorial](http://tjhouston.com/2012/03/merge-info-from-google-forms-to-pdf-document-and-send-via-email/) and was able to get it work. The problem is the UI (Spreadsheet form) is not what I wanted. I want a form in HTML but unable to pull data correctly from it.

Here is a sample script I created using Spreadsheet Form.

```
var docTemplate = "1234567890";  // Template ID
var docName     = "FinalDocument";   // Name of the document to be created

// When form gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) { 
// Get information from form and set as variables
  var email_address = e.values[1]; 
  var full_name = e.values[2];

// Get document template, copy it and save the new document's id
  var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
               .makeCopy(docName+' for '+full_name)
               .getId();
// Open the temporary document
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document's body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
  copyBody.replaceText('keyEmailAddress', email_address);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyFullName', full_name);

// Save and close the temporary document
   copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
   var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 

// Attach PDF and send the email
   var subject = "Final Document";
   var body    = "Here is the form for " + full_name + "";
   MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf}); 

// Delete temporary file
   DocsList.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

And here is the new form using HTML I just created.

```
<html>
  <form id="myForm">
   <input name="fullName" id="_fullName">
   <input name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress">
   <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick = "sendData()">
  </form>

  <script>
    function sendData() {
     google.script.run.processForm(document.getElementById("myForm"));
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Could someone help me get started on how to transition from using Spreadsheet form to HTML form? How do I pull data from the HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to this question which I asked before at [Accessing object is Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425473/accessing-object-is-google-app-script)

So for your case it should be:

```
  // Get information from form and set as variables
  var email_address = e.emailAddress; 
  var full_name = e.fullName;
```

And as for your HTML code

```
<html>
  <form id="myForm">
   <input name="fullName" id="_fullName">
   <input name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress">
   <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick = "google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode)">
  </form>
</html>
```

Please give a try, I did not have time to test the code. So sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help shh. I tried your code, but couldn't get the result in the Logs. Any idea?

function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myForm.html');
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate();
}

function processForm(e) {
  
  Logger.log(e.fullName);
  Logger.log(e.emailAddress);
}